# How can this buying logic be achieved using drupal commerce and/or ubercart?

Tags: views, commerce

I think the following scheme describes best what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I am trying to make a ticket booking "shop" if you will.

- There are different events
- For each event you can buy tickets, like the graphic above shows
- There are different ticket types, like normal, vip and special vip (for instance)
- Each ticket type can vary in its price depending on the date
- The visitor should be able book several tickets for that event at once
- Optional: beneath the table is a summary of the selected tickets/ total price
- The visitor can checkout and pay, gets a summary (different story)

**My attempts so far**

On an existing drupal project I installed the commerce module.

I installed [commerce booking](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_booking) since it pretty much claims to do what I am looking for. Unfortunately there has been a bug in this module for several months making it unusable, there is no fix there yet (https://www.drupal.org/node/2134449 for instance). What a bummer.

So I installed **drupal commerce kickstarter** and tried around a little bit in here.

I came up with a product type/ variation "Event", two taxonomy vocabs "Ticket Type" and "Date" and added taxonomy reference fields to the event/ product type.
The cool thing is I can now add a new event "Jam session at Alex's" and add many **product variations** in it.
For instance I can add a variation which's price is 1 €, pick a term for a date like "Date 01" and pick a term for the type of ticket like "Ticket Normal". With these fields I can add x numbers of product variations to actually depict the variety of tickets as shown in the graphic. So far so good.

However, I cant manage to create an output like shown in the graphic, how would you do that with views? How could you implement an ajax quantity indicator (it actually should work like the add to cart form, but with AJAX) and adding a payment process right after? Help would be greatly appreciated.

I havent tried to use ubercart yet, would it be far more easy to do it with uc, maybe?

Comment: got most of the above scheme working, using add to cart extra quantity field, taxonomies and views matrix fyi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to be easy to do with either Drupal Commerce or Ubercart. What you're proposing is a very specific, custom bulk Add to Cart form. You're going to have to code it yourself in a site-specific module. The closest you can get would be Commerce Cart Extras, but you'd still have to reformat it to look like your proposed grid and also to have a live updating order total in the footer.